# Examples of $U$-split parallel pairs of compact Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $f,g\colon X \to Y$ are maps of compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ and $Y$. Their *coequalizer* $\pi \colon Y \to Z$
is the set $Z:=Y/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $f(x)\sim g(x)$. The map $\pi$ sends $y$ to its equivalence class, and $Z$ is given the quotient topology. It’s easy to see that $Z$ is compact, but it may not be Hausdorff. However, under the following kind of strange assumption, one can show that $Z$ is always Hausdorff. Assume that there are functions $\iota\colon Z \to Y$ and $s\colon Y \to X$—these are *not* assumed to be continuous—such that
$$ \pi \iota = 1_Z,\quad gs = 1_Y,\quad fs = \iota\pi. $$

In this situation, the foregoing data is altogether called a “$U$-split coequalizer” for reasons which I’ll say a bit about at the end.

I was trying to come up with an interesting example, e.g. one where the maps $s$ and $\iota$ are not continuous, and I failed. I am looking for an example of the above situation where $s$ and/or $\iota$ is not continuous, or at least one that isn’t just collapsing pieces of a disjoint union.

---

Here is a non-interesting example: Let $$X=[0,1]\times\{0,1,2\},\quad Y = [0,1]\times \{0,1\}.$$ Define $f$ and $g$ as follows.
$$f(t,n) = \begin{cases} (t,0) & n = 0,1 \\ (t,1) & n = 2 \end{cases}\qquad g(t,n) = \begin{cases} (t,0) & n = 1 \\ (t,1) & n = 1,2\end{cases}$$

It’s not hard to see that $Z = [0,1]$, that $\iota\colon Z \to Y$ is perhaps $t\mapsto (t,0)$, and that $s\colon Y \to X$ could be $s(t,n) = (t,n)$.

---

*Here’s a short explanation of the category theory mumbo jumbo motivating this question:* Let $U\colon$ **cHaus** $\to$**Set** be the forgetful functor from the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and continuous functions to the category of sets and functions. As part of [Beck’s monadicity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck's_monadicity_theorem), to prove that **cHaus** is monadic over **Set**, one needs to show that $U$ *creates* coequalizers of $U$-split parallel pairs.

That is, given just the data of $f,g\colon X\to Y$, the following is true. If on the level of underlying sets, we can find $\pi$, $\iota$, $s$ and $Z$ exactly as above, only missing the assumption that $Z$ is a topological space and $\pi$ is continuous, then actually $Z$ can be given a topology that makes $\pi$ continuous and satisfy the universal property of the coequalizer, which I’d prefer not to define. In other words, given a coequalizer $\pi\colon Y \to Z$ of underlying sets with the extra information of the “splitting” functions $\iota$ and $s$, then actually $\pi\colon Y\to Z$ is the underlying function of sets of a continuous function. We say $U$ *creates* this coequalizer.

Comment: So the question is to show that $U$ "creates coequalizers" (whatever that means) of $U$-split parallel pairs? Could you state what the requirement means?

Comment: oh, yes, sorry! It turns out that this isn’t relevant to my question, but I’ll edit now.